# Разбивка строки по длинее и переносу строки

Tags: php, массивы, строки, циклы

Есть такая функция, которая разбивает строку на части заданной длинны:

```
function split($str, $len = 5) {
  $arr    = [];
  $length   = mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i += $len) 
  {
    $arr[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $len, 'UTF-8');
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

На выходе получается массив состоящий из строк длинною до 5 символов.

Нужно модифицировать функцию таким образом, чтобы одним из условий переноса был символ новой строки /n. Тоесть, перенос совершается в рамках 5 символов, но если встречается знак переноса, делаем разбитие в этом месте. Это нужно чтобы перенос по возможности не рвал слова на части

Те, если исходная строка имеет вид,

```
$str = '12345/n9101111/n2';
```

на выходе должно получаться:

```
1=>12345 (5)
2=>678/n (4)
3=>91011 (5)
4=>11/n (3)
5=>2 (1)
```

Уточнение: Например есть строка длинною 150 символов, ее нужно разбить на блоки максимальной длинною 50 символов, в строке встречаются переносы на новую строку. Задача разбить строку на такое количество блоков максимальной длинной 50 символов чтобы как можно меньше "разрывать" слова по возможности разбивая блоки на местах переноса строки, пусть они будут и короче 50 символов. Но в случае если переносы строки не встречаются, то разбивать на последнем пробеле. Ну или если уж нет пробелов, то тогда разбивать на 50-м символе. Скриншот тут иллюстрирует проблему i.stack.imgur.com/EqfmR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "12345\n9101111\n2";
preg_match_all('~.{1,5}\n?~', $str, $m);
$ret = array_map(function($s){ return rtrim($s, "\n"); }, $m[0]);
var_dump($ret);
```

Возвращает

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "12345"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "91011"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "11"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Comment: Total Pusher, спасибо, но немного не то. Скорее всего я некореектно поставил задачу. Нужно разбивать строку так, чтобы по возможности не разрывались слова и предложения, а перенос совершался по наиближаешему "\n". Может по скриншоту будет понятнее))
[![screenshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqfmR.jpg

В идеале, это чтобы 12-й пункт уже был в новом блоке (строке)

Comment: Переформулируйте исходный вопрос.

Comment: Например есть строка длинною 150 символов, ее нужно разбить на блоки максимальной длинною 50 символов, в строке встречаются переносы на новую строку. Задача разбить строку на такое количество блоков максимальной длинной 50 символов чтобы как можно меньше "разрывать" слова по возможности разбивая блоки на местах переноса строки, пусть они будут и короче 50 символов. Но в случае если переносы строки не встречаются, то разбивать на последнем пробеле. Ну или если уж нет пробелов, то тогда разбивать на 50-м символе. Скриншот тут иллюстрирует проблему https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqfmR.jpg

Comment: Пожалуйста, поправьте исходный вопрос, в начале страницы. Шоты также вставляйте тут. Иначе ваш вопрос никому не будет интересен и утонет

Answer (score 0):

```
function chunk_split_unicode($str, $l = 5, $e = "\r\n", $last = FALSE) {
    $tmp = array_chunk(preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY), $l);
    $res = [];
    $count = (count($tmp) - 1);
    foreach ($tmp as $k => $t) {
        $res[] = (($count != $k) OR ($last)) ? implode('', $t) : implode('', $t) . $e;
    }
    return $res;
}

function new_split($str, $len = 5) {
    $arr = [];
    $str = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
    $count = (count($str) - 1);
    foreach ($str as $k => $value) {
        $arr = array_merge($arr, chunk_split_unicode($value, $len, PHP_EOL, ($count != $k) ? FALSE : TRUE));
    }
    return $arr;
}

$str = '12345678
9101111
2';
var_dump(new_split($str));
```